# Lock LaunchScreen.xib orientation on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone-6-plus, launch-screen

I am using a LaunchScreen.xib to start my app. This xib must works in portrait mode (only!). Anyone knows how can I achieve that with an iPhone 6/6s Plus (they can start the app in landscape)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you open the Attributes Inspector for the assets catalog then you need check the landscape box like image[image]

Hope my solution help you to resolved your issue.

Comment: Hi @Cuong Nguyen, thanks for the reply but I can't use Assets Catalog in my project. I'm using a single xib that can be defined in the project's main target (general settings) and in the info.plist

Comment: Hi guy. 
If you using file .xib and info.plist. Try it info.plist 
https://gist.github.com/cuong-nguyen-ta/5822e74c8d029bdcc73f

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation:

**Launch Images**

> Launch images for iPhone apps are always sized to match the dimensions
>   of the screen in portrait orientation. For applications that launch
>   into landscape orientation, you should use your preferred graphics
>   editing software to rotate the content of the launch image while
>   keeping the image's size consistent with a portrait launch image
>   (height > width).
>
> Avoid using asset catalogs to manage the launch images of landscape
>   applications. **Except for launch images used by the iPhone 6 Plus,
>   asset catalogs assume that all iPhone launch images are for the
>   portrait orientation.** When your application is compiled, entries for
>   each launch image are added to the compiled information property list
>   under the UILaunchImages key. The value for the
>   UILaunchImageOrientation key in each of these entries is always
>   Portrait. These entries are then ignored at launch time because the
>   value of Portrait for the UILaunchImageOrientation key does not match
>   the launch orientation (Landscape Left or Landscape Right). The result
>   is a blank screen during launch as the system cannot find an
>   appropriate launch image.
>
> Instead, you should use a Launch File if your application only
>   supports iOS 8 and above. Otherwise, you will need to add your launch
>   images as resources to your project and then add the UILaunchImages
>   key to your application's information property list. Be sure to
>   disable use of the asset catalog for managing the launch images by
>   selecting 'Don't use asset catalogs' from the Launch Image Source menu
>   under the General tab of the project editor for your applications'
>   target.

For more [info:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2244/_index.html)

If you are not using assets, use `UILaunchImages` key to make changes to the launchscreenimage in your application's information property list and then edit the value under each `UILaunchImageName` key to match the corresponding image from your project. Do not include the extension or any modifiers (@2x, @3x). You can edit your information property list by control+clicking on it in the File Navigator and choosing Open As > Source Code from the popup menu.